# LSTM RNN application

Tags: lstm, multilabel-classification

I am a newbie to machine learning. I am figuring out a way to predict student outcomes (pass, fail, drop-out)using LSTM? I have attributes to take into account - gender (M/F), previous grades (Pass, Fail, Distinct), age (0-35,35-55, >=55) and interactivity (sum of clicks) of each student with virtual learning environment for each day. I have interaction data for each day. Can I use LSTM/RNN on this kind of data?

The interaction data is of 280 days.

Please help!